# Admin trail head crm basics

Tags: administration

[image: Account Detail]

I also tried the role setup in the Users but there's no use

[image: Challenge Not yet complete]

[image: Account Detail]

Comment: I did the each and every step in this trail correctly but it shows an error

Comment: can you please post the screenshot of that account, account team and contact role of that account.

Comment: Are you setting the newly created Contact 'John Smith' as the Account Manager or the current user?

Comment: John Smith needs to be a contact role on green dot not Acme. Acme should be the account john smith is related to directly

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. If you post a question, there should be an actual question somewhere in the text. Image only questions or answers tend to be low quality and are not very accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "Account Manager" in Account Contact Role and Add yourself as a member into Account Team.

+edit:
Go to Setup | Build | Contact Roles on Accounts - Add "Account Manager" to the Roles.

Please edit the Account Page Layout, Go to Related List | Add the Contact Roles Tab in layout and save.

Now click on "New" in Contact Roles Related List to create a New record in that tab.

There are two Accounts involved in this scenario, Acme Corporation & Greendot Media.

->Add a New contact & a Contact Role(Account Manager) to Acme Corporation. Add yourself as an Account Manager in Account Team related list.

->Now Add a Relationship of that Contact for Greendot Media Account(do not create, add a relation with the existing contact JohnSmith).

I hope you might have enabled relationship settings for account by following the above steps in trialhead.

Comment: Thanks for the response , i edited my question and added the screenshots plz go through them.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please let me know if it answers ur question

Comment: i made the changes but there is no use it again shows the same error.i'm adding the screenshot check it once

Comment: Please check the answer I made some changes

Answer (score 0):

Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The 'John Smith' contact role for 'Greendot Media' could not be found.
Relate a Contact to Multiple Accounts. Then add Yourself to an Account Team.

Your VP just connected you to a new contact, but the contact works with two different companies. To pass this challenge, relate the new contact to the two different accounts. Then, add yourself to the account team. In order to complete this challenge, you need to have Contacts to Multiple Accounts and Account Teams enabled. The Related Contacts and Account Teams related lists must be on the Account page layout. The Related Accounts related list must be on the Contact page layout.

Create an account with the Account Name 'Acme Corporation'.
Create an account with the Account Name 'Greendot Media'.
Create a contact with First Name = 'John', Last Name = 'Smith'. In the Account Name field, enter 'Acme Corporation'.
From the Greendot Media account record, use the Related Contacts related list to add a relationship with John Smith.
Add yourself to the account team for the 'Acme Corporation' account with the Team Role of 'Account Manager'.